# SQL & ColdFusion Encryption

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, coldfusion, cryptography

I know how to encrypt data using ColdFusion using AES_128. I also know how to encrypt data using MSSQL AES_128. Does anyone know if it’s possible to encrypt data in ColdFusion using AES_128, then decrypt the string in MSSQL?

I’ve played around with it a lot and can’t seem to figure it out.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Did you try to use passphrase encryption/decryption on both sides?

Comment: Yes I've tried that already. I don't think you can use an advanced algorithm like AES with passphrase in sql.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible.  There is nothing about AES that makes it proprietary.  However,  there are many ways of implementing a block cipher,  and most of them are incorrect. MS SQL's [encryptbykey()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) uses ECB mode and defaults to ANSI_PADDING.  I would try decrypting a message using the same key with an AES in ECB mode and it will likely *just work*.  CBC mode should be used,  but this requires a IV,  and `encryptbykey()` doesn't accept an IV as a parameter so its ECB mode.  (MySQL also ecb mode,  i've looked at the code.  Its a shame I can't do that with MS SQL).

Comment: I am using the encryptbykey() method already. I'm able to encrypt and decrypt the string in SQL however I think the issue that I'm having is that MSSQL using a Symmetric key to encrypt and decrypt the data and the server-side language I'm using (which is ColdFusion) also requires a key however I am unable to replicate that key in ColdFusion because as far as I know you can't actually view the contents of the Symmetric key correct? I've tried using the Symmetric key's gui_key but this didn't work.

Comment: @Paul aes is a symmetric cipher. gui_key() is a string2key function and has nothing to do with symmetry,  its actually a message digest.   You could use another string2key function,  or randomly generate a key and there for you wouldn't need a string2key function.