# Encrypt in Single Store and Decrypt in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, aes, singlestore

I have a dataset in Single store. The objective is to encrypt a few columns within Single store, load the data into a SQL Server instance and then decrypt it there using an encryption key.

1. I tried using the AES_ENCRYPT function in single store. I encrypted a sample data with a specific key using the aes-128-ecb algorithm.
2. While loading and testing decryption in SQL server using DECRYPTBYKEY, I found that even though SQL server supports AES-128 encryption, it doesn't support encryption with different modes such as ECB, GCM or CBC which single store utilizes.

Looks like DECRYPTBYKEY on SQL Server can only decrypt the data encrypted by ENCRYPTBYKEY.

What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: I can't actually find it *documented* anywhere, but I've stumbled across several posts (such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671236/2029983)) that denote that SQL Server does use ECB by default. As such, if you've used AES-128-ECB then decryption with AES-128 in SQL Server should work (as it should be AES-128-ECB). Have you actually tried decrypting your data, and seeing if it works? *Also, don't forget the most common mistake (I see) when decrypting: inconsistent data typing and code pages. A UTF-8 `varchar` and an ANSI `varchar` or UCS-2 `nvarchar` are different.*